# Concatenate a field value with string - Lotus Notes

Tags: string, field, concatenation, lotus-notes

I have a formula based on a field value called text_TTArs ( data/time field -> showing only the time, eg: 15:31 ).

The formula is smth like this: @Hour(text_TTArs)*60+@Minute(text_TTArs). This returns a number.

What I want to do is to appear after this number: %. I've tried

(@Hour(text_TTArs)*60+@Minute(text_TTArs))&"%" but it isn't working. I've tried + instead & but it's the same.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert it to a string first:

```
@Text(@Hour(text_TTArs)*60+@Minute(text_TTArs)) + "%"
```

(always use "+" to concatenate in @Formulas. "&" is the symbol for a logical "AND")

Comment: It shows: ERROR: Incorrect data type for operator or @Function: Number expected. The result appears on a view column

Comment: It sounds like text_TTArs is a text field/value, not date/time. How is the field defined on the form? WHoever created the field is clearly naming it with a text- prefix...

Comment: It is date/time editable and it is showing only the time (eg: 15:41). The name of the field is text_TTArs, but it isn't a text field.